# format float with minimum and maximum number of decimals

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I'd like to format a float with minimum 2 and maximum 8 decimals. I do it like this:

```
def format_btc(btc):
    s = locale.format("%.8f", btc).rstrip('0')
    if s.endswith(','):
        s += '00'
    return s
```

Is there a way to do it only with format() function?

edit:

examples: left is float, right is string

```
1 -> 1,00
1.1 -> 1,10 (I have now realised that my code returns 1,1 for this example; that's a bug)
1.12 -> 1,12
1.123 -> 1,123
1.12345678 -> 1,12345678
1.123456789 -> 1,12345678
1,1234567890 -> 1,12345678
```

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I rechecked the [specification language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to make sure. Possible reasons:

1. (Theoretical) If 8 digits after decimal are significant, then deleting 0s deletes information.
2. (Practical) The complication of adding a third number argument used only for floats and then very seldom is not work the rare gain.